# Cannot get all POST Success xml data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to take my xml marker results and load them onto a map, however the post result I get in my variable when I alert is this:

> Data Loaded: [object XMLDocument]

This is what my code looks like:

```
function SendData() {

//get data from inputs

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "MapSearchxml.php",
                data: {
                    dataFromDate: FromDate,
                    //some more data
                    dataHasPatio: HasPatio
                },
                beforeSend: function (html) { // this happens before actual call
                },
                success: function (html) { // this happens after we get results

                alert("Data Loaded: " + html);

                }
            });
}
```

In Firebug, the post response looks like this:

> `<markers><marker id="1" lat="48.153938" lng="17.108459" /></markers>`

I tried setting the datatype to xml like this:

```
                success: function (html) { // this happens after we get results
                alert("Data Loaded: " + html);
                }, 
                dataType: 'xml'
            });
}
```

However no change happened.

Here's my xml php code:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}


header("Content-type: text/xml");

echo '<markers>';

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'id="' . parseToXML($row['ID']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . parseToXML($row['LAT']) . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . parseToXML($row['LNG']) . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

echo '</markers>';
```

Comment: What are you expecting to be returned? Can you also show your PHP code?

Comment: Hey mccannf, I'm expecting this whole thing to be returned `<markers><marker id="1" lat="48.153938" lng="17.108459" /></markers>`. I'll edit my post with the php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the browser handles XML objects when appending them to a text string and displaying the data in an alert. Your ajax call looks like it's working.

You could try changing:

```
    success: function (html) { // this happens after we get results
       alert("Data Loaded: " + html);
    },
```

to just:

```
    success: function (html) { // this happens after we get results
       console.log(html);
    },
```

and view the object in the JavaScript console.
or:

```
    success: function (html) { // this happens after we get results
        var xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(html);
        alert("Data loaded: " + xmlString);
    },
```