# Cannot load Google Maps Markers from XML variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've searched all over the place and tried finding other causes of issues to no avail.
I have a search form to retrieve xml data, and the data comes back great.

> Response Headers
>
> Content-Type  text/xml;charset=utf-8 Date Fri, 04 Jan
>   2013 19:00:52 GMT Server  Apache Transfer-Encoding    chunked Via 1.1
>   decfpxy1 (NetCache NetApp/6.0.2)
>
> Response:

```
<markers><marker id="1" lat="48.153938" lng="17.108459" /></markers>
```

However my `data` variable doesn't insert anything into my script that loads the markers and I get this error:

> TypeError: xml is undefined [Break On This Error]
>
> var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

This is the code:

```
function SendData() {




    var FromDateUnformatted = $('#from').val().split('/');
    var FromDate = FromDateUnformatted[2] + '-' + FromDateUnformatted[0] + '-' + FromDateUnformatted[1] + ' 00:00:00';
    var ToDateUnformatted = $("#to").val().split('/');
    var ToDate = ToDateUnformatted[2] + '-' + ToDateUnformatted[0] + '-' + ToDateUnformatted[1] + ' 23:59:59';
    var MusicStyles = $("#music").val();
    var Locations = $("#locations").val();
    var FromPrice = $("#entrance-price").slider("values", 0);
    var ToPrice = $("#entrance-price").slider("values", 1);
    var IsOutdoors = +$('#IsOutdoors').is(':checked');
    var HasPatio = +$('#HasPatio').is(':checked');


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MapSearchxml.php",
        data: {
            dataFromDate: FromDate,
            dataToDate: ToDate,
            dataMusicStyles: MusicStyles,
            dataLocations: Locations,
            dataFromPrice: FromPrice,
            dataToPrice: ToPrice,
            dataIsOutdoors: IsOutdoors,
            dataHasPatio: HasPatio
        },
        beforeSend: function (html) { // this happens before actual call
            $("#results").html('Please Wait');
            $("#searchresults").show();
            $(".phpFromDate").html(FromDate);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //clearOverlays();
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var name = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));

                var html = "<b>" + point + "</b>hello <br/>";
                var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("redmarker.png");

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: point,
                    icon: icon.icon,
                    shadow: icon.shadow
                });

                bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
            }
        }
    });



    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }

}
```

Here is the PHP file itself:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}


header("Content-type: text/xml");

echo '<markers>';

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'id="' . parseToXML($row['ID']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . parseToXML($row['LAT']) . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . parseToXML($row['LNG']) . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

echo '</markers>';
```

I've used variations of this code to retrieve a static xml php file without any problems, but with this code, I am unable to take the results from this post and insert them into my marker-builder correctly.

I've done tons of research here and on google and I can't seem to find any alternatives anywhere.

Do you know what the issue could be?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried pointing your browser at the dynamically generated XML?  Is it valid?  From the answer to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161967/cannot-get-all-post-success-xml-data), it looks like you want to use: `var xml = data`, rather than data.responseXML.

Comment: Hey geocodezip, [everything looks good](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/PHPSearchForm/MapSearchxml.php).

Comment: This doesn't look correct to me: `<markers><marker id="" lat="" lng="" /></markers>`. Might be valid XML, but will not display markers.  Is the actual query returning data?  Does your code correctly handle the case when it doesn't?

Comment: I was confused by it too since my query is written like this `if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)`, however [you can go here](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/PHPSearchForm/search_clubbing.php), set the `from` date to January 3rd and hit Map Search. I now have a new error, however you can see the post results in Firebug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "map" variable is local to the onload function, it isn't available in the global context in which the AJAX callback routine runs, so it isn't defined correctly when you use it here:

```
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icon.icon,
                shadow: icon.shadow
            });
```

To make it global, do a `var map;` in the global context (outside any function), then initialize it in your onload function (as you are now, just remove the "var" from in front of it).

Comment: Wow, I am getting there almost! Do you know why I am getting `ReferenceError: infoWindow is not defined` error? I thought I had everything and google has no answers.

Comment: The error: `ReferenceError: infoWindow is not defined` usually occurs when the infoWindow variable is not defined (hint: it isn't defined).  You need to define it and initialize it somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

the first argument provided to the success-callback is not a (jq)XHR-object, it's the data(depending on the request this may be a string, a  JSON-string parsed into an object, or a **document** ) .

None of them will have a property `responseXML`.

So you may either use the document directly:

```
var xml = data;
```

or use the third argument:

```
success: function (data,status,jqXHR) {
         var xml = jqXHR.responseXML;
         //....
         }
```

But whatever you do, you better specify the `dataType:'xml'`     for the request, to be sure that the successfully result will be an xml-document .

Comment: Thanks, however I think that this will never be solved :D! [Here's how I formatted the script now](http://jsfiddle.net/cUKBF/). The error now is `Error: Invalid value for property <map>: [object HTMLDivElement]` in main.js loaded automatically from google. I will try to find out more about the error myself.

Comment: The error says that you assign a DIV-element to  the map-property of an object (but it must be a google.maps.Map-object). Impossible to help you without seeing the complete scripts

Comment: Sounds like IE.  Do you declare your google.maps.Map object with the "var" keyword?  Does it have the same name as the id of HTML div that contains it?  To fix that error, we need to see the definition of the map.

Comment: Sure, you can see the [whole script here](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/PHPSearchForm/search_clubbing.php). The map function starts at the bottom, and the top part is not related to the map.

Comment: MapSearchxml.php always returns `<markers>
<marker id="" lat="" lng=""/>
</markers>`

Comment: I fixed that just a little while ago. What's weird now is that it only returns 1 response. However if you set the `from` date back to december 1st, it should return some 6. I am looking into the [php code](http://jsfiddle.net/hfSAu/), however it's almost identical to my other scripts with the exception that they have a static query while this one changes depending on the search function. Notice the normal `search` button in my example returns more than 1 results if you set the `from` a month back.