# Google Maps API V3 Marker not showing due to undefined variable

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having difficult getting my markers to show with the Google Maps V3 API.

I get the below error when I load the page -

**TypeError: xml is undefined**

var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

I've tried declaring the xml variable in a few different ways but to no avail.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
function load() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.765558,-122.450867),
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("phpsearch.php", function(data) {
    xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");//<- error occurs right here
//Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of undefined
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}


function downloadUrl(url,callback) {
 var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
     new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
     new XMLHttpRequest;

 request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (request.readyState == 4) {
     request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
     callback(request.responseText, request.status);
   }
 };
 request.open('GET', url, true);
 request.send(null);
}
```

Page is here:

http://www.students.bl.rdi.co.uk/stu26984/index2.php

It seems like the fixes for the below question should have helped but I can't figure out why I am still being told the variable is undefined.

[Cannot load Google Maps Markers from XML variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163297/cannot-load-google-maps-markers-from-xml-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `downloadUrl` function passes the response text not a response object to your callback. You can change the function to pass the required object. Ofcourse you have to be receiving xml in your response.

```
function downloadUrl(url,callback) {
 var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
     new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
     new XMLHttpRequest;

 request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (request.readyState == 4) {
     request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
     callback(request, request.status);//right here
   }
 };
 request.open('GET', url, true);
 request.send(null);
}
```

Comment: That did it, thanks a million! That could have taken me weeks to figure out.